# Edit the int.random to be set by the user and issue with corner radius

Tags: swift, random, int, uilabel, cornerradius

I am just getting started with Swift and I would like the user to be able to set the range of the Int.random for example : if he want to have a random number in the range of 0 to 100, he can set it here.

The view of the settings:

[image: The view of the settings]

Basically it should change my function numberGenerator, at the moment the default range is 0 ... 10000 but I want it to adapt when the user want to change it.

My code at this moment:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var numberGenerated = 0



    @IBOutlet weak var labelNumber: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var generateButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func generateButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        numberGenerator()

        labelNumber.text = String(numberGenerated)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labelNumber.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        labelNumber.clipsToBounds = true

        generateButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        generateButton.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    func numberGenerator() {
        numberGenerated = Int.random(in: 0 ... 10000)
    }


}
```

And I have another issue, when I change the cornerRadius of the labelNumber it doesn't show any difference like the generateButton.

The result when I run the app at this moment:

[image: The result when I run the app at this moment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you obviously need to add min and max UITextFields into the view.

Once you have done that, create an outlet for each of them and then just use the dynamic values.

```
func numberGenerator() {
    let min = Int(minTextfield.text)
    let max = Int(maxTextfield.text)
    numberGenerated = Int.random(in: min...max)
}
```

Comment: Great, If this resolved the issue please mark it as the accepted answer (by clicking the greyed out tick icon) to show the question is solved. thanks

Comment: I did like you said : func numberGenerator() {
        let minChoice = Int(minTextField.text ?? 0)
        let maxChoice = Int(maxTextField.text ?? 100)
        numberGenerated = Int.random(in: minChoice ... maxChoice)
    } BUT I got an error "Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String'" and when it handle it with the String() : numberGenerated = Int.random(in: minChoice ?? 0 ... maxChoice ?? 100)
    } I got a new error but now in the numberGenerated which said :  "Binary operator '...' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Int?' "